# Existing custom UIButtons distort when adding a new one

Tags: ios, uibutton, interface-builder, storyboard

My iPad app has a row of custom UIButtons and I want to add another row underneath, roughly in the position of the Round Rect Button shown:
[image]

However, when I try to resize the new button to match the existing ones, the existing buttons distort:

[image]

Can anyone tell me why this happens and / or how to avoid it? Thanks.

Comment: @H2CO3: slightly puzzled as to why you removed the x-code tag from my question?

Comment: as it currently stands, the question is not about Xcode, it's about the usage of the Cocoa Touch frameworks on iOS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Select the button from the XIB and then goto the 5 tab of the Inspector.

From the Inspector select the View Section and then Turn off the Autoresizing property by click the arrow.

Your Autoresizing should look like this : [image]

All the best !!!

Comment: Thanks but which tab is the % tab? I have File, Quick Help Identity, Attributes, Size & Connections.

Comment: Got it now - attributes inspector. Thank you.

Comment: As an aside, I just had to go through this process again after reinstalling provisioning profile, despite not changing anything in code or storyboard at all. Weird.

Answer (score 1):

you are getting this issue because of auto size property.

Specify you can remove this from size inspector from Utilities Panel

click on you button and remove autosize property.

You can also remove programmatically by setting `setAutoresizingMask:`

Comment: Thanks - issue resolved from above answer but your post is useful too.