# UIImageView is shifting down when viewed on 4 inch iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch

I am trying to figure out what settings for the UIImageView below will work with all device sizes.

I'm getting no luck with every combination I've tried.

Here's the .xib:

[image]

When I run this on a 4" the image is shifted down much lower from the top label and the buttons stay put.

I have the top label set to Top, tried Aspect Fit/Fill for it as well, didn't change anything.  Seems to be an issue with the UIImageView.  Also saw someone mention try clip subviews, have that selected, still can't keep it the same size and orientation when going back and forth from 3.5" to 4" iphone on device and simulator.

Comment: Have you tried setting "Autosizing" from Size Inspector ?

Comment: use Autosizing and make label and image with top and left resize . remove all other resize.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hope this helps, in your case you should keep it to the default setting, no change required..

[image]

Answer (score 0):

First if turn off the Autolayout setting from XIB.

Now visit [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15246601/existing-custom-uibuttons-distort-when-adding-a-new-one/15246697#15246697).